# Always open a new/fresh tab/window using Android browser intent

Tags: android, android-intent

It's a simple request from a simple man.

I am running some OAuth challenge stuff in my code and I want the user to always see a fresh new page on the browser.

I have seen a whole bunch of threads; but none of them really answer this question.

Here's how I am creating an Android browser intent (using `c#`/Xamarin):

```
static void GoToAndroidBrowserWithLoginUri(Activity activity, Uri uri)
{
    Intent oauthIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
    activity.StartActivity(oauthIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with intent flags you can do this:

```
oauthIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

update: what happens if you add this category to the intent:

```
oauthIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
```

if that doesn't work, lets create a separate task for these activities. Add these flags only:

```
oauthIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); //clear whats already in your task list                                                             
oauthIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);//create a new task to contain the activity
```

Comment: I do understand the second part of your answer; but I don't understand what you describe in the first example. Maybe you didn't get the question; I am trying to open the browser from the application; how does affective the activity in the application affects my intent for the browser application.

Comment: Fair enough. I am going to try this code and accept the answer shortly. Thanks.

Comment: Just saw your update. `ClearTask` and `NewTask` seem to do the job. :)